# Remove leading whitespace from a Word document

Tags: vba, ms-word

How can I remove all leading whitespace (spaces, empty lines) from the first page of a Word document?

Comment: did you try anything, do you have any initial code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: It turns out what I wanted was to remove all empty paragraphs, or paragraphs consisting only of whitespace, from the start of the document. The following macro `DeleteLeadingWhitespace` does this and also preserves formatting.

```
' return True if the character at the given position is a whitespace character.
' codepoints courtesy of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character#Unicode
Function IsSpace(ByVal Text As String, Optional ByVal Position As Long = 1)

    Select Case AscW(Mid(Text, Position, 1))
        Case &H9, &HA, &HB, &HC, &HD, &H20, &H85, &HA0, _
                &H1680, &H180E, &H2000, &H2001, &H2002, &H2003, &H2004, &H2005, &H2006, _
                &H2007, &H2008, &H2009, &H200A, &H2028, &H2029, &H202F, &H205F, &H3000
            IsSpace = True

        Case Else
            IsSpace = False
    End Select

End Function

' return True if the paragraph consists only of whitespace
Function IsParagraphEmpty(ByVal pg As Paragraph)

    Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To Len(pg.Range.Text)
        If Not IsSpace(pg.Range.Text, i) Then
            IsParagraphEmpty = False
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next

    IsParagraphEmpty = True
End Function

' delete leading whitespace from the given document.
Sub DeleteLeadingWhitespaceFrom(ByVal Document As Document)

    While IsParagraphEmpty(Document.Paragraphs.First)
        Dim i As Long
        i = Document.Paragraphs.Count

        Document.Paragraphs.First.Range.Delete

        ' no change in number of paragraphs, bail
        If i = Document.Paragraphs.Count Then Exit Sub

    Wend

End Sub

' macro: delete leading whitespace from the active document
Sub DeleteLeadingWhitespace()

    DeleteLeadingWhitespaceFrom ActiveDocument

End Sub
```